# How to filter database to look for missing observations

Tags: r, filter, time-series, missing-data

I am attempting to do quality control on my coral database to find corals that were observed, then were not seen during the next observation, and then was found again in a subsequent observation.  When this occurs in the database, it means the coral was actually already dead but because it was not observed in the previous observation, there appears to be a gap in the database.

#### Database

```
data <- structure(list(Site = c("WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", 
"WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI"), `Module #` = c(111, 
111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 113, 113, 113, 113, 113, 114, 114
), Side = c("N", "N", "N", "N", "S", "S", "S", "N", "N", "N", 
"S", "S", "N", "N"), TimeStep = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 
3, 2, 4, 1, 2), `Colony #` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 5, 5), `Taxonomic Code` = c("PC", "PC", "PC", "PC", "PR", 
"PR", "PR", "PC", "PC", "PC", "MO", "MO", "PC", "PC"), `Cover Code` = c(1, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, NA), `Max Diameter (mm)` = c(3, 
6, 10, 13, 2, 5, NA, 2, 5, NA, 4, NA, 2, NA), `Max Orthogonal (mm)` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Height (mm)` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Status Code` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "NF", NA, NA, "D", NA, "D", NA, "NF"), Notes = c("Data is fine and can be filtered out", 
NA, NA, NA, "TimeStep 3 the colony was not measured or observed, want to filter for this case", 
NA, NA, "Colony was found dead during TimeStep 3 and is fine to be filtered out", 
NA, NA, "Colony not measured in TimeStep 3 but found dead in TimeStep 4, want to filter for this case", 
NA, "Colony was not found in the second quarter, fine to be filtered out because there are no gaps in the data", 
NA)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `Module #` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), Side = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), TimeStep = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Colony #` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Taxonomic Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), `Cover Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Max Diameter (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), `Max Orthogonal (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
"collector")), `Height (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
"collector")), `Status Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Notes = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

My goal is to filter for unique corals (`Colony #`) that have a gap present in the data where an observation is missing from the previous TimeStep.  So for example you can see that for `Colony #` == 2, TimeStep 3 is missing.  Therefore, for #2, I want to filter for all entries in the database that have `Colony #` == 2.

The desired database looks as follows:

#### Desired Database

```
data_desired <- structure(list(Site = c("WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI", "WAI"), `Module #` = c(111, 
111, 111, 113, 113), Side = c("S", "S", "S", "S", "S"), TimeStep = c(1, 
2, 4, 2, 4), `Colony #` = c(2, 2, 2, 4, 4), `Taxonomic Code` = c("PR", 
"PR", "PR", "MO", "MO"), `Cover Code` = c(1, 1, NA, 1, 4), `Max Diameter (mm)` = c(2, 
5, NA, 4, NA), `Max Orthogonal (mm)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `Height (mm)` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Status Code` = c(NA, 
    NA, "NF", NA, "D"), Notes = c("TimeStep 3 the colony was not measured or observed, want to filter for this case", 
    NA, NA, "Colony not measured in TimeStep 3 but found dead in TimeStep 4, want to filter for this case", 
    NA)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    Site = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Module #` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Side = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), TimeStep = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Colony #` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Taxonomic Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `Cover Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Max Diameter (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `Max Orthogonal (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), `Height (mm)` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
    "collector")), `Status Code` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Notes = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Thank you in advance for any and all input on this issue.  I hope to filter for corals that have a TimeStep missing so I can go back to check the full database for corals that have missing data.

Comment: Why not just give only the relevant columns?

Comment: Are there always only a max of 4 TimeSteps per colony (looks like a quarterly variable)? If so, based on your example, would you want Colony 3  (it has values for TimeStep of 1,2,3 and none for 4) and Colony 5 (only has values for TimeStep of 1 and 2) in your ```data_desired``` output too? You expected output dataframe only shows Colony 2 (only TimeStep values of 1,2,4) and Colony 4 (only TimeStep values of 2,4)

Comment: Yes I do want to fill in the gaps of the database.  However, this is a simplified example.  In my real database, corals were found at various points throughout the study.  Because of this, the TimeStep variable spans from 1 to 12 and as mentioned, corals were found at various times through those TimeSteps.  My goal was to just filter for these instances where the colony was dead `Status Code` == "D" or "NF" so I could fill in the gaps.  That filling in the gaps part though I was going to make a separate post for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a less convoluted way of doing this but here's an attempt:

EDIT: Adjusted code assuming `Colony #` is a factor.

```
library(tidyverse)

# First find the maximum TimeStep for each `Colony #`
# Note that dataset is sorted by `Colony #`
iMaxTimeStep <- data %>% 
  arrange(`Colony #`) %>% 
  group_by(`Colony #`) %>% 
  filter(TimeStep == max(TimeStep)) %>% 
  .$TimeStep

# Then find the `Colony #`s which will be filtered in by builiding a dataframe with 
# what would be expected to be seen in terms of TimeStep and `Colony #`s.
# We use anti_join to see what;s missing from our data
iColonies <- data.frame(TimeStep = unlist(sapply(iMaxTimeStep, function(x) seq(1, x))),
                        Colony   = factor(rep(levels(data$`Colony #`), iMaxTimeStep))) %>%
  setNames(c("TimeStep", "Colony #")) %>% 
  anti_join(., data, c("TimeStep", "Colony #")) %>% 
  .$`Colony #` %>% 
  unique

# Finally, filter in only the selected `Colony #`s
res <- data %>% filter(`Colony #` %in% iColonies)

# Result
res
```

UPDATE:

Based on the additional comments, the following solution accepts different starting `TimeStep`s for each `Colony #` (and is a little bit more elegant):

```
library(tidyverse)

iColonies <- data %>%
  arrange(`Colony #`, TimeStep) %>% 
  group_by(`Colony #`) %>% 
  summarise(MinTimeStep = min(TimeStep),
            MaxTimeStep = max(TimeStep),
            .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(TimeStep = map2(.x = MinTimeStep, .y = MaxTimeStep, ~seq(from = .x, to = .y))) %>% 
  unnest(TimeStep) %>% 
  anti_join(., data, c("TimeStep", "Colony #")) %>% 
  .$`Colony #` %>% 
  unique
    
res <- data %>% filter(`Colony #` %in% iColonies)

#Result
res
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the ```[r]Colony   = rep(1:5, iMaxTimeStep)``` portion generic instead of specific to `Colony #` 1-5?  The reason I ask is because in my real dataset, the `Colony #` column is actually a factor column such as "H2" or "W55" for example.

Comment: In other words, I want to make it so that iColonies will run for all coral colonies.  I have some 3000 individual colonies with factorized names (eg. "W55") so I want this code to not specify a numeric range but rather a generic range that captures all coral colonies

Comment: I've updated the code to take into account that `Colony #` is a factor and to use it's levels when creating the full dataframe. Also note that `iMaxTimeStep` will need to have the `data` sorted first.

Comment: When I substitute my full database into your provided code, I receive the following error: ```[r]Error in data.frame(TimeStep = unlist(sapply(iMaxTimeStep, function(x) seq(1,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 32754, 0``` The problem may be that in your code, you are assuming that corals were all observed in the first TimeStep?  This is not reality as corals were observed for 12 quarters (TimeStep 1 - 12) and were found during different points in those 12 quarters.

Comment: Please let me know if you need me to put a head of my full database in order to figure out the kinks in your code.

Comment: A minimal example database (one which exhibits all relevant possibilities) would be preferable, but if the only remaining difference is that not all corals were observed in the first TimeStep, I think I should be able to suitably amend the code without it, once I get some spare time.

Comment: Yes if you are able to address the point with the ability for corals to be first observed at any point I believe that would solve the issue.

Comment: @EricDilley Did you get the chance to check if the updated code works for your data?

Comment: Thank you for this update.  This is very close to being what I was looking for.  The only issue is that when I plugged in my full database, the resulting filtered database includes corals that a.) were observed for the first time after TimeStep == 1 and b.) did not have any missing data (breaks in the sequence of TimeSteps from 1 to 12).  Point a.) is fine to have but only if there is a gap in the TimeStep sequence for a given coral colony.  Please let me know if you need an example but it seems this would take just a minor tweak.  Thanks again for your efforts!

Comment: One last note, I am looking for specifically are corals where there was a gap in TimeStep (eg. TimeStep 2, 3, 5 with no 4) and the next observation (in this case TimeStep 5 but could be later TimeSteps if not observed for multiple quarters) has `Status Code` equal to either "NF" or "D".  Once the above two comments are incorporated, this should work well

Comment: Are you sure about this? Because I tried it by changing Colony's 5 TimeSteps to 2 and 3 (from 1 and 2 as they currently are) so that (a) they don't start at TimeStep == 1 and (b) didn't have any missing TimeSteps, and the code did not report colony 5 in the results.

Comment: Thanks after reviewing this again, it worked.  I think it could have been a package interference issue on my end.  Thank you for your time and I have marked your solution as an accepted answer